# Problems bringing up a second virtual network interface

Tags: networking, ubuntu-12.04, interface

I'm having issues adding a second IP address to one interface.  Below is my `/etc/networking/interfaces`

```
   # The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#eth0 is our main IP address
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
 address 198.58.103.*
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 198.58.103.1

#eth0:0 is our private address
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
 address 192.168.129.134
 netmask 255.255.128.0

#eth0:1 is for www.site.com
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
 address 198.58.104.*
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 198.58.104.1
```

When I run `/etc/init.d/networking restart`, I get a fail error about bringing up `eth0:1`:

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0:1.
```

Any reason this would be?  I didn't have any problems with I first set up `eth0` and `eth0:0`.

Comment: Remove the second gateway 198.58.104.1

Comment: For future readers, I did still have to reboot even after I removed the second gateway.

Comment: /etc/init.d/networking restart has always been problematic for me.  Always best to do a full machine reboot.

Comment: with current Debian based systems syntax has changed: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427414/virtual-nic-siocsifflags-cannot-assign-requested-address-but-gets-created/545844#545844

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:**

The problem is you have 2 default gateway's defined.  You need to remove one of them.
I would think the one on the eth0:1 device.

The file exists error is being thrown by attempting to add the default route again which is already in place.

---

Firstly, I presume the * as the host number is a valid number and not literally a '*'?

Now try it this way.  I suspect there is a problem with the parsing of the auto line in the startup scripts - just a hunch, I haven't looked.

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#eth0 is our main IP address
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
 address 198.58.103.*
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 198.58.103.1
 # Put your nameserver address here!
 dns-nameservers x.x.x.x 

#eth0:0 is our private address
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
 address 192.168.129.134
 netmask 255.255.128.0

#eth0:1 is for www.site.com
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
 address 198.58.104.*
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 # This shouldn't be here!  remove it.
 #gateway 198.58.104.1
```

And secondly, to get rid of the annoying resolv.conf error run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Although this is a separate issue.

Comment: Fixed my resolv.conf issue.  Edited my question, still seeing the same issue after breaking out the auto line.

Comment: Try a full reboot.  I've not had much success with networking restart personally.  It's not always cleanly restarted.  Failing that, try changing eth0:1 to eth0:2

Comment: Also don't change your question too much.  It won't be useful if you solve it and make it right.  e.g. you've now removed the resolvconf stuff.

Comment: True.  I removed it since it obviously wasn't a part of the real issue.

Comment: Remove the second gateway

Comment: Removed the second gateway and still couldn't get it to work.  Rebooted and everything is working now.

Comment: The two gateways of the same physical netcard seemed to be the problem for me too. To avoid rebooting, I did: ifdown eth0:1; ifconfig eth0:1 down; ifup eth0:1. It then came up without any erros/warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Also this:

```
ifdown eth0:0 
ifdown eth0:1 
ifdown eth0
ifup eth0
```

The `ifup eth0` at the end starts both the primary and the alias AND only sets the route once.

Comment: Fixed the resolv.conf issue

Comment: Alright, I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

With current Debian based systems syntax has changed. The key is to use format of address with slash subnet `address 192.168.129.134/17`, and not to use `netmask` keyword anymore.

The preferred method for Debian based system is to use networking configuration files.

The alias method prefers to use such order: `eth0, eth:0:0, eth0:1,` ...

So first alias to system would be eth0:0 and to achieve this persistent across system reboots, create a file `/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0` with such content:

```
auto eth0:0
allow-hotplug eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
      address 192.168.129.134/17
```

Or you can edit directly the file `/etc/network/interfaces` but this is not recommended as it can be overwritten automatically.

Afterwards do

`service networking restart`

to test the configuration.
Check afterwards with command:

`service networking status`

and

`ip address`